# Fabric toDataUrl with multiplier not working as expected

Tags: html5-canvas, fabricjs

In my code I created method to clip images using fabric shapes. I have used stackoverflow answer for achieving this. Somehow after using this method I cannot render the canvas using default fabric canvas render method.

```js
var img01URL = 'https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png';
var img02URL = 'http://fabricjs.com/lib/pug.jpg';

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

document.getElementById('download').addEventListener('click', function() {
  canvas.renderAll();
  this.href = canvas.toDataURL({
    format: 'png',
    multiplier: 2        
  });
  this.download = "test.png";
}, false);

var clipRect1 = new fabric.Rect({
    originX: 'left',
    originY: 'top',
    angle: 90,
    left: 195,
    top: 0,
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    fill: '#DDD', /* use transparent for no fill */
    strokeWidth: 1,
    lockMovementX: true,
    lockMovementY: true,
    angle: 5,
    stroke: 'red'
});

var pugImg = new Image();
pugImg.onload = function (img) {    
    var pug = new fabric.Image(pugImg, {
        angle: 0,
        width: 500,
        height: 500,
        left: 245,
        top: 35,
        scaleX: 0.3,
        scaleY: 0.3,
        clipName: 'pug',
        clipTo: function(ctx) { 
            ctx.save();
            ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
            clipRect1.render(ctx);
            ctx.restore();
        }
    });
    canvas.add(pug);
};
pugImg.src = img02URL;
pugImg.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
```

```css
#c {
    border:0px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.bootcss.com/fabric.js/1.5.0/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="500" height="400"></canvas>
<a id="download">Download as image</a>
```

Comment: Does anyone knows method?

Comment: Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.  Did you notice this in your console?

Comment: i removed the not used functions from the fiddle for clarity if someone wants to help. You should submit a clean example if asking for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is the multiplier.
When using that kind of clipTo functions, you are setting the transform of canvas to plain. When rendering with canvas with multiplier, the base canvas transformation is scaled by the multiplier.

Your rect will be drawn without this transform ( because of setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0) and will clip out the image.

Instead of setting the transform to [1,0,0,1,0,0] you should set to the invers of the current transformation of the object you are clipping.

```js
var img01URL = 'https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png';
var img02URL = 'http://fabricjs.com/lib/pug.jpg';

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

document.getElementById('download').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var data = canvas.toDataURL({
    format: 'png',
    multiplier: 2        
  });
  console.log(data);
  //var img = document.getElementById('export');
  //img.src = data;
}, false);

var clipRect1 = new fabric.Rect({
    originX: 'left',
    originY: 'top',
    angle: 90,
    left: 195,
    top: 0,
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    fill: '#DDD', /* use transparent for no fill */
    strokeWidth: 1,
    lockMovementX: true,
    lockMovementY: true,
    stroke: 'red',
    angle: 5
});



var pugImg = new Image();
pugImg.onload = function (img) {    
    var pug = new fabric.Image(pugImg, {
        angle: 0,
        width: 500,
        height: 500,
        left: 245,
        top: 35,
        scaleX: 0.3,
        scaleY: 0.3,
        clipName: 'pug',
        clipTo: function(ctx) { 
            ctx.save();
            var myMatrix = this.calcTransformMatrix();
            myMatrix = fabric.util.invertTransform(myMatrix);
            ctx.transform.apply(ctx, myMatrix);
            clipRect1.render(ctx);
            ctx.restore();
        }
    });
    canvas.add(pug);
};
pugImg.src = img02URL;
```

```css
#c {
    border:0px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="//www.deltalink.it/andreab/fabric/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="500" height="400"></canvas>
<a id="download">Download as image</a>
<img id="export" >
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I'll try this and let know the result

Comment: You are correct about the multiplier. But how to set inverse of current transform?

Comment: It can be done now i see... the code i posted in clipTo function gets the inverted matrix, but i see that there is no easy way to get the clipped object reference (this) in the function... maybe we need an update of clipTo method, or maybe i'm just wrong now

Comment: Ignore my comment. simply you needed newer version for this code that i linked in the snippet.

Comment: Is this customized fabric version you using? I get "TypeError: this.calcTransformMatrix is not a function" when using fabric 1.6.0-rc.1

Comment: After using fabric.js file you provided its work like a charm. Thank you for this. Hope this will come out with the new version.

Comment: In this fabric.js file there's a issue with shadows. "this.isRetinaScaling is not a function"