# FabricJS ClipPath not scaling properly on toDataUrl with multiplier

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I'm using Fabric JS 3.6.2

I have a responsive canvas where I can add props and configure a "game tile" to my liking, here's [the branch build](https://5ec988fe9e4b6a00065f508e--rollinitiative.netlify.app/home?page=room) I'm having problems with. I'll add the steps to replicate the problem further below.

I use the canvas to add a lot of image files, and have recently started to implement clipPath's to the wall and floor.

Since the canvas itself is downscaled compared to the end output, I have to add the mask and rescale it compared to the relative size of the added images *after* the images are loaded onto the canvas using *fabric.Image.fromURL*. To solve this I use the *rescaleMask* function in the accepted answer from [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52715580/3202733)

When I'm happy with what I have created I can generate an image from the canvas using toDataUrl(), but I need to either upscale the canvas to the correct output size or use a multiplier property in toDataUrl() to get the correct output size. 
Everything except the clipPaths scale correctly.

```
toDataUrl() {
    var self = this;

    // self.resizeCanvasFullscreen();// Alternative solution part 1

    var calculatedMultiplier = self.store.canvasSettings.width / $("#canvasContainer").width();
    var pngUrl = self.canvas.toDataURL({
      format: "image/png",
      multiplier: calculatedMultiplier});

    // self.resizeCanvasResponsive(); // Alternative solution part 2
    return pngUrl;
  },
```

A slight contradiction to that: 
When the last thing I did was to clear the canvas, then add all images and attach clipPaths, canvas.toDataUrl has no problems. But if the last thing I did was to add a new object to the canvas, then canvas.toDataUrl won't rescale the clipPath properly. Here's a comparison:

canvas.toDataUrl() right after everything is added:

[image: Generate image when canvas is newly rendered]

canvas.toDataUrl() right when canvas just got a new object:

[image: Generate image when canvas just got a new object]

To replicate this using the link posted at the top:
- Open link, select base type (Stone or wood)
- Click "Generate image" below the canvas, everything should work fine and a saveable-image is generated in the list below
- Click the "Props" tab and add any prop available by clicking it (Or dragging it out there)
- Click "Generate image" again, notice the clipping which occurred

Note: If I remove the multiplier (and don't rescale the canvas before save) the clipPath scaling works. Although the end output isn't the size it has to be so this isn't a valid solution.

The closest StackOverflow answer I can find [is this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35716553/fabric-todataurl-with-multiplier-not-working-as-expected), but it's meant for clipTo, and I can't figure out how to make this happen with the clipPath setup I have now. Is this still a big step in the correct direction on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer my own question, embarrassingly - Remember when I said: "To solve this I use the rescaleMask function in the accepted answer from [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52715580/3202733)"

Turns out I had experimented a bit with that function, I've replaced two lines:

```
mask.scaleX = 1;
mask.scaleY = 1;
```

With:

```
mask.scaleX = target.scaleX;
mask.scaleY = target.scaleY;
```

As target.scaleX and scaleY always was 1 at the point the masks where set, it was no problem and worked like a charm initially.

My guess is that after I added an object to the canvas it must have been updated with the downsizes scales, so when the canvas was resized during the canvas.toDataUrl() with multiplier, it used the downsized target.scaleX and target.scaleY, which was not 1 at that point.

If you are in the same or similar scenario, try the rescaleMask function found in the link above, and see where that gets you! (Not sure if I should mark this question as a duplicate?)